# Why do I get 'Storage not available. Aborting hit.' with Google Analytics?

Tags: debugging, google-analytics

I'm setting up with the new Google Analytics tracking code.

```
<script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'MYUACODE', 'MYDOMAIN');
      ga('send', 'pageview', {
          'page': '/setup',
          'title': 'Setup Page'
        });

    </script>
```

I've got this inside my HEAD tag as Google tell you to do
Obviously MYUACODE and MYDOMAIN are the real variables in my page :)

However when I run this using Google Chrome and I turn on the Google Analytics Debug extension, I get the following message:

```
Registered new plugin: "linker"       analytics_debug.js:5
Creating new tracker: t0              analytics_debug.js:5
New visitor. Generating new clientId  analytics_debug.js:5
Storage not available. Aborting hit.  analytics_debug.js:5
```

It seems to fire up correctly and starts setting up the items, but then it says **Storage not available** and it seems nothing ever gets to Google.

Now if I remove all this code and go back to the original Google Tracking code, it works fine, I just can't seem to get this new style to fire correctly.

Any thoughts? Help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I had the same error message.  It seems to be related to not being able to set the cookie correctly.  In my case, it happened when I was testing off localhost and I hadn't set my cookieDomain to none.

You may want to try something like the following and see if it works.  I'm not sure if the method of passing your domain that you have works.

```
ga('create', 'MYUACODE', {
  'cookieDomain': 'none'
});
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Only the difference is I'm not on local i.e. I'm on www.foobar.com and mentioning the same domain in the code still does not work.

Comment: i needed to add storage: none to make this solution work and I also provided clientId hash manually as written here 
worked also on GTM implementation
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#automatic_cookie_domain_configuration

Answer (score 13):

Google Analytics used to generate the tracking code with the hostname hard coded in the `create` method, which could cause this error when testing on a different hostname. Now when GA generates the tracking code it uses

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
```

which automatically determines the cookieDomain value. Changing the hardcoded hostname to `'auto'` in this method call has fixed this issue for me on several sites that had the old tracking code generated.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, most of the options presented will work. However, they all should be applied in different scenarios. Please refer to [GoogleA's Domains & Cookies - Web Tracking (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains) for the full list.

I handled my client's situation a bit differently to deal with language variants, one of which was on a separate domain. Below you'll see the domain followed by the tracker creation call:

1. en.client.en, ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'client.en');
2. fr.client.com, ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'client.com');
3. de.client.com, ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'client.com');
4. xx.client.com, ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'client.com');

The reason I did not use

> ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto')

or 'none' for the domain parameter was because that configuration is unlikely to track subdomains. My client will probably want view conversions by country / language. Thus, the account will have the grouped view (configured above), as well as individual views filtered by subdomain (country / language). In the Google documentation, it clearly states under Automatic Cookie Domain Configuration:

> Analytics.js will fail to write a cookie on co.uk but will succeed on
>   example.co.uk. Since a cookie was succesfully written on a higher
>   level domain, www.example.co.uk will be skipped.

and under Setting cookies on localhost (where cookieDomain is set to 'none'):

> Note: This will set a host only cookie domain. The cookie will not
>   propgate to any subdomains. However, Internet Explorer does not follow
>   this pattern.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Playing with 'MYDOMAIN' resolved the problem for me

```
ga('create', 'MYUACODE', 'MYDOMAIN');
```

i removed 'MYDOMAIN' at all and leaved it like

```
ga('create', 'MYUACODE');
```

restarted the page, then added `, 'MYDOMAIN'`n again and this worked

The second time i faced with the problem it solved the problem to change 'MYDOMAIN' to the domain i was loading the page from (from production domain to my hosting domain)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add a domain to your host file and then use that instead of localhost. Mine looks like:

`127.0.0.1    localhost mytest.com`

Use mytest.com instead of localhost and you will be able to check your info and you won't have to add any options to the ga create method call.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was with another extension in chrome. Using an empty profile (--user-data-dir=/tmp/foo) resolved the problem for me.