# Google Analytics bugs

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I already read all solutions on the internet but haven't found how to fix the my error.  Firstly, in Google Chrome Mac there is a warning:

> "Storage not available. Aborting hit."

[image]

I need to send events. In Chrome they won't work via analytics.js. So I use the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide) directly via ajax and post to `https://www.google-analytics.com/collect`.  However the problem is now that it don't have the data of traffic source by utm. I see my traffic source, I see my events but no connection between them (in any browsers).

I'm looking into Google Tag Assistant chrome extension - there is an error "No HTTP response detected".

Google Tag Assistant Chrome extension IMAGE:
[image]

I tried anything, to set the "ga('create',..., 3rd param)" 3rd param to 'auto', to my domain with and without www, to set cookieDomain: none, nothing don't help. (in addition, if I sent to 'auto' it write an error "Cookie not set")
I tried also on new blank HTML page with the code from google, the same problem.

Comment: Without the complete code it's really hard to help

Comment: As @Dekel mentioned its hard to help if you don't show us the full call you are sending to the measurement protocol.   However you need to remember that using the measurement protocol directly means that you are responsible for sending the values for all of the parameters you whish to track.  Analytics.js does most of this for you automatically I suspect you are missing some of the traffic source values. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#trafficsources

Comment: it's the same code that Google gives..

Comment: put the exact code you use, even if it's the same one

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-83998413-1');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

Comment: When I send with event "ga('send', 'event')" everything is OK in all browsers, even in IE, expect chrome! in chrome it says "Storage not available. Aborting hit." and don't send event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get 'Storage not available. Aborting hit.' with Google Analytics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992734/why-do-i-get-storage-not-available-aborting-hit-with-google-analytics)

Comment: Yes but i tried all - still not working. Maybe its a bug in Chromium?.... its not working in Chrome and Opera (based on Chromium)

Comment: I found that its some problem in my computer.. the debug of analytics on this site stackoverflow also says "Storage not available. Aborting hit.". At another computer its ok.... dont know what, i have the newest mac os and chrome.